# How to Interpret Interaction Between Two Categorical Variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interpretation

I am having some difficulty attempting to interpret an interaction between two categorical/dummy variables. For example, lets say there is an interaction term between an individual's gender and her race.

`sex=1 if male & race=1 if white`

There is an interaction term between sex and race `sex*race`

Let's say this is the regression model:

`wage = 0 + 1*educ + 2*sex + 3*race + 4*(sex*race) + e`

How would you interpret 4 in this model? I presume it would be that if an individual is male and white, his wage will increase by 4. 2 would be if an individual is male, his wage will increase by 2+4*race and 3 would be if an individual is white, then his wage will increase by 3+4*white. Is this a correct interpretation? If not, please help me understand any flaws in my intuition. I appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: Related: [Interpretation of betas when there are multiple categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/120030/7290), & [Interpretation of interaction term](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122246/7290).

Answer (score 5):

Your interpretation is true. This is another way to interpret these terms:

- If the person is *male* but not *white*, the wage is increased by $\beta_2$ (or decreased if $\beta_2$ is negative).
- If the person is not *male* but is *white*, the wage is increased by $\beta_3$.
- If the person is *male* **and** *white*, the wage is increased by $\beta_2+\beta_3+\beta_4$. That is, the term $sex *race$ makes your model **non-linear**. Without this term, if the person is *male* and *white*, the wage is increased by the amount of increase if he is *male* plus the amount of increase if he is *white*, which is one property of linear models. In other words, this term places more emphasise on the employees that are both *male* and *white*.

Comment: Thank you show much, that was extremely helpful and intuitive. I have another question regarding your comment, I apologize if this is stupid. Regarding your part where you stated "makes your model **nonlinear**", does this not violate the first CLRM assumption of having a linear population model?

Comment: No, it does not violate this assumption, because according to this assumption, your model should be linear in **parameters**, but it does not require the model to be linear in **variables**.

Comment: When you say "If the person is male and white, the wage is increased by β2+β3+β4", what do you compare too? What is reference category? Is it men who is black?
woman who is white? or
woman who is black?

Comment: They are all comparing to the case where both dummy variables are 0, so, that is black women.

Comment: @AndersMadsen If I correctly get your question, we compare to the case where either the person is woman or black. (The complement of `A and B` is `not(A) or not(B)`). In this case (where the person is woman or black), we cannot say that the wage is increased by `β2+β3+β4`, and it is obviously increased by a different value for different combinations of sex and race.