# Why weighted glm coefficients differ from weighted mean?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, propensity-scores, weighted-regression

Let's consider the following `dataframe`:

```
d = data.frame(Sex  =factor(rep(c("Male","Female"),times=2), levels=c("Male","Female")),
           Race =factor(rep(c("White","Black"),each=2),  levels=c("White","Black")),
           y    =c(1, 3, 5, 7),
           weights = c(0.01,0.03,0.02,0.01))
> d
    Sex  Race  y weights
1   Male White 1 0.01
2 Female White 3 0.03
3   Male Black 5 0.02
4 Female Black 7 0.01
```

Let's assume that the weights are inverse propensity scores. If we calculate the weighted means for `Sex` categories, we get this:

```
       Sex  y
mean(Male): 3.66
mean(Female): 4
#i.e., the difference is 0.34
```

However, if we fit a `glm` on the above data and plugged weights in, we obtain the following coefficient estimates:

```
Call:
glm(formula = y ~ Sex + Race, data = d, weights = w)

Deviance Residuals: 
1  2  3  4  
0  0  0  0  

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        1          0     Inf   <2e-16 ***
SexFemale          2          0     Inf   <2e-16 ***
RaceBlack          4          0     Inf   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0)

    Null deviance: 0.22857  on 3  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.00000  on 1  degrees of freedom
AIC: -Inf

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1
```

in which, the estimated coefficient for `SexFemale` is 2. Note that if we exclude the `weights = weights` we still obtain the same coefficients but with different estimates. Now I'm wondering why the two mean difference differs? What can I say about the mean difference in this situation? Should I based my evaluation on `glm` estimates or what?

Comment: Your computation of weighted means does not control for race.  Your GLM does.  What does it look like if you just estimate glm(formula = y ~ Sex, data = d, weights = w)?

Comment: @TheLaconic Thanks. Will post the result of the model you requested shortly. However, if the reason is not controlling for race, why the coefficient and means are the same when we don't have weights? pls see this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120030/interpretation-of-betas-when-there-are-multiple-categorical-variables

Comment: Coincidence.  That model fits your made-up data perfectly, whether you weight it or not.