# Interpreting logistic regression coefficients for a categorical variable

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I got these results from a logistic regression in R. The data are the proportion of women elected in Uk elections, according to their party.

[image]

As you can see, I used `exp()` to get rid off of the log function, so these are the odds, **not the log odds**.

How can I interpret these, since I don't see how I can say that for every 1 unit increase in party, there is an increase in the odds. Are these odd ratios comparing with each other, I mean comparing with the odd ratios for all other parties?

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a 'discrete' variable, it's a *categorical* variable.  Only the intercept is the odds of a woman (in the reference level party) being elected.  The other coefficients are *odds ratios*.  You multiply those odds ratios times the odds in the intercept to get the odds of a woman in the, say, green party being elected (in that case the odds is .3125, or about 24%).

It may help you to read:

- [Interpretation of simple predictions to odds ratios in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34638/7290)
- [Interpretation of betas when there are multiple categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/120035/7290)

Comment: Thanks man. First let me tell you that I consider you a legend haha. Just another silly question: where that 24% comes from? And, just to make sure, R compares every of those values against the reference that is in this case the Conservative Party, which the intercept, right?

Comment: @RafaelHernándezSalazar, the indicated levels are compared to the reference level. To convert from odds to a probability, you do `o/(1+o)` (see the thread linked in my answer above).